# Get device name php

Tags: php

I know that it is not possible to obtain the device name (e.g. PC-Francesco) but I was wondering what an alternative solution could be to obtain a unique string for the device.  I need it to then make a comparison during login and check if the device is set in the db as blocked.  I was thinking of merging the provider name + operating system + device type.  Do you have any other better solution?  Type is it possible to get the serial number or the model number of the device?  thanks i hope you can help me

Comment: then it will help you [stackoverflow : how to identify remote machine uniquely in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1198106/8676838)

Comment: There's no way to get a truly unique string from a device. There can always be collisions. That's a good thing when it comes to privacy though. To try and get it as unique as possible, you can just grab as much info client info as possible from the `$_SERVER`-variable and hash it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to identify remote machine uniquely in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198094/how-to-identify-remote-machine-uniquely-in-php)